# In Unix while-do loop the comparision condition is failing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

The input files are:

Schema of file1 is :

```
offer rank score lat lon eligiblecms
```

File 1:

```
10000,1,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
12345,2,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
13245,3,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
11111,4,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
11112,5,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
```

Schema of file 2 is:

```
offer1 rank1 score1 lat1 lon1 eligiblecms1
```

File 2

```
10000,1,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
12345,2,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
13245,3,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
11111,4,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
11112,5,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32152,6,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32153,7,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32154,8,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32163,9,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32164,10,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32165,11,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32167,12,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32170,13,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32171,14,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32182,15,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
32183,16,0.0,"-31.940742,115.86829",3760006987500
```

I have the  code as  :

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=,
read offer rank score lat lon eligiblecms
#dataflag="F"
do
while IFS=,
read offer1 rank1 score1 lat1 lon1 eligiblecms1
do
 if [ "$offer" = "$offer1" ]
 then
echo "Details of Offer $offer   :"
      if [ "$lat" = "$lat1" ] && [ "$lon" = "$lon1" ]
      then
      echo "Expected latlong "$lat", "$lon" successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: "$lat1,$lon1" "
 else
      echo " Expected latlong "$lat","$lon" did not  matched with the Latlong of API output offer "$offer1" "
      fi
 if [ "$eligiblecms" = "$eligiblecms1" ]
 then
         echo " Expected UID "$eligiblecms" successfully  matched with the UID of API output offer "$eligiblecms1" "
 else

         echo " Expected UID "$eligiblecms" did not  matched with UID of API output offer "$offer1" "
         fi
 fi
done <$1
#if [ "$dataflag" = "F" ]
#then
#echo ""$offer" not found"
#fi
done <$2
```

Whose ouput is :

```
 Details of Offer 10000   :
Expected latlong "-31.940742, 115.86829" successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: "-31.940742,115.86829"

     Expected UID 3760006987500 did not  matched with UID of API output offer 10000
    Details of Offer 12345   :
    Expected latlong "-31.940742, 115.86829" successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: "-31.940742,115.86829"

     Expected UID 3760006987500 did not  matched with UID of API output offer 12345
    Details of Offer 13245   :
    Expected latlong "-31.940742, 115.86829" successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: "-31.940742,115.86829"

     Expected UID 3760006987500 did not  matched with UID of API output offer 13245
    Details of Offer 11111   :
    Expected latlong "-31.940742, 115.86829" successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: "-31.940742,115.86829"

     Expected UID 3760006987500 did not  matched with UID of API output offer 11111
    Details of Offer 11112   :
    Expected latlong "-31.940742, 115.86829" successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: "-31.940742,115.86829"

     Expected UID 3760006987500 did not  matched with UID of API output offer 11112
```

I am not sure why I am not able to get the specified condition ture for my code anytime ,it should be ture as per my logic.

```
"$eligiblecms" = "$eligiblecms1"
```

I am getting the output as :

```
Expected UID 3760006987500 did not  matched with UID of API output offer 11112
```

As per my logic output should be:

```
Expected UID "$eligiblecms" successfully  matched with the UID of API output offer "$eligiblecms1
```

Please help.

Comment: `[ "$dataflag"="F" ]` is a bug, as it will always be true. You are not testing what you think you are. Change it to `[ "$dataflag" = "F" ]`. As an aside, you are combining the POSIX-compliant `[` with the Bash-only `==`. I would suggest using `[` with `=` everywhere. If you prefer `==` from familiarity with other languages, use `[[`.

Comment: Your error messages are telling you what the problem is: you need to use double quotes around your variables: `[ $eligiblecms = $eligiblecms1 ]` should be `[ "$eligiblecms" = "$eligiblecms1" ]`. Alternatively, if you use Bash's extended tests you don't need the quotes (and you can use `==` if you really prefer): `[[ $eligiblecms = $eligiblecms1 ]]`.

Comment: Thanks Tom,I have rephrased my question,I believe now you can get a better idea.

Comment: Use `set -x` to check what is being executed and make sure that your variables have the values you expect. Also, as a general piece of advice, change `echo "Expected latlong "$lat", "$lon" successfully...` to `echo "Expected latlong \"$lat\", \"$lon\" successfully...`.

Comment: Every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. The guys who invented the UNIX shell to sequence calls to UNIX tools invented the UNIX tool awk to manipulate text. Don't let them down :-).

Comment: Please, check there is no trailing blank at the end of each line. If a trailing blank exists then `[ "3760006987500" = "3760006987500 " ]` is FALSE.

Comment: To check the issue about trailing blanks, I'd suggest the following command:  `"echo ">>$eligiblecms|$eligiblecms1<<"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to write your script:

```
$ cat tst.awk                
BEGIN {
    FS = "[,\"]+"
    offer       = ++enum
    rank        = ++enum
    score       = ++enum
    lat         = ++enum
    lon         = ++enum
    eligiblecms = ++enum
}

NR==FNR { file1[$offer] = $0; next }
{
    if ( $offer in file1 ) {
        split(file1[$offer],expd)
        split($0,act)

        print "Details of Offer " act[offer] "   :"

        if ( (act[lat] == expd[lat]) && (act[lon] == expd[lon]) ) {
            print "Expected latlong " expd[lat] ", " expd[lon] " successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: " act[lat] "," act[lon]" "
        }
        else {
            print " Expected latlong " expd[lat] "," expd[lon] " did not  matched with the Latlong of API output offer " act[offer] " "
        }

        if ( act[eligiblecms] == expd[eligiblecms] ) {
            print " Expected UID " expd[eligiblecms] " successfully  matched with the UID of API output offer " act[eligiblecms] " "
        }
        else {
            print " Expected UID " expd[eligiblecms] " did not  matched with UID of API output offer " act[offer] " "
        }
    }
    else {
        print $offer, "not found"
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
Details of Offer 10000   :
Expected latlong -31.940742, 115.86829 successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: -31.940742,115.86829 
 Expected UID 3760006987500 successfully  matched with the UID of API output offer 3760006987500 
Details of Offer 12345   :
Expected latlong -31.940742, 115.86829 successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: -31.940742,115.86829 
 Expected UID 3760006987500 successfully  matched with the UID of API output offer 3760006987500 
Details of Offer 13245   :
Expected latlong -31.940742, 115.86829 successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: -31.940742,115.86829 
 Expected UID 3760006987500 successfully  matched with the UID of API output offer 3760006987500 
Details of Offer 11111   :
Expected latlong -31.940742, 115.86829 successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: -31.940742,115.86829 
 Expected UID 3760006987500 successfully  matched with the UID of API output offer 3760006987500 
Details of Offer 11112   :
Expected latlong -31.940742, 115.86829 successfully  matched with the Actual  Latlong: -31.940742,115.86829 
 Expected UID 3760006987500 successfully  matched with the UID of API output offer 3760006987500 
32152 not found
32153 not found
32154 not found
32163 not found
32164 not found
32165 not found
32167 not found
32170 not found
32171 not found
32182 not found
32183 not found
$
```

idk i I managed to duplicate your logic correctly but hopefully it's clear enough that you can twek it where necessary. I tried to use syntax as similar as possible to what you were already using so it's easiest for you to understand if you don't know awk.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton,it looks great,can you plz explain the **code**,that would be really helpful.

Comment: @anusngh no, it's all very basic awk so just refer to the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins and I'll be happy to answer any specific questions.